# ajax mysql lookup not returning correct result for multi word string

Tags: ajax, string, codeigniter, space

I have followed a [tutorial](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_17/Check_the_user_name_availability_with___Codeigniter_jQuery) on an ajax lookup that informs the user if the username is already taken.

So the controller syntax is:

```
<?php
    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {
        function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('loginView');
        }
        function getResultfromdb($username){

            $this->db->where('username',$username);
            $query = $this->db->get('users')->num_rows();
            if($query == 0 ) echo 'userOk';
            else echo 'userNo';
        }
    }
```

the view is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check User Name</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">

            <label for="username">Enter Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="username"/>
            <span class="checkUser" ></span>
            <input type="hidden" class="hiddenUrl"/>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/check.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

the check.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#username').blur(function(){

        if( $('#username').val().length >= 3 )
            {
              var username = $('#username').val();
              getResult(username); 
            }
        return false;
    })
    function getResult(name){
        var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
        $('.checkUser').addClass('preloader');
        $.ajax({
            url : baseurl + 'index.php/login/getResultfromdb/' + name,
            cache : false,
            success : function(response){
                $('.checkUser').removeClass('preloader');
                if(response == 'userOk') $('.checkUser').removeClass('userNo').addClass('userOk');
                else $('.checkUser').removeClass('userOk').addClass('userNo');;
            }
        })
    }
})
```

As mentioned, this works great. so it will validate `bob` and `andy` perfectly. however it fails on `bob smith` and `andy jones`. How can the code be adapted to validate strings with spaces?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because you're trying to pass the username in the URL, the browser is likely encoding the space as %20 when passing it. So your CI function is looking for bob%20smith and not bob smith.

First of all I don't think it's great practice to even allow spaces in user names but to each their own. You need to decode the URL first

```
 function getResultfromdb($username){

            $this->db->where('username',urldecode($username));
            $query = $this->db->get('users')->num_rows();
            if($query == 0 ) echo 'userOk';
            else echo 'userNo';
        }
```

Comment: CI escapes SQL injections when using active record on it's own.

Comment: my mistake, I was thinking in terms of not validating user input, because he is not using the form validation class.

Comment: All good, was waiting for your response just to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious lol. I never mind learning new things, particularly when it comes to securing apps.

Comment: Hi Gents, Thanks for the input. I am not actually using this for the username, that's just the tutorial. I will be checking a customer name and as such these are normally multi word names. `Massmart pyt ltd` etc. Thanks, will try the above and revert.

Answer (score 0):

use the `encodeURIComponent(string)`,for example :

```
var name = encodeURIComponent(name);
```

and you js will look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#username').blur(function(){

    if( $('#username').val().length >= 3 )
        {
          var username = $('#username').val();
          getResult(username); 
        }
    return false;
})
function getResult(name){
    var name = encodeURIComponent(name); // Replace name before send it
    var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
    $('.checkUser').addClass('preloader');
    $.ajax({
        url : baseurl + 'index.php/login/getResultfromdb/' + name,
        cache : false,
        success : function(response){
            $('.checkUser').removeClass('preloader');
            if(response == 'userOk') $('.checkUser').removeClass('userNo').addClass('userOk');
            else $('.checkUser').removeClass('userOk').addClass('userNo');;
        }
    })
}
})
```

and the php :

```
<?php
$url = urldecode($_GET['name']); // Replace with your parameter 
?>
```

Okay good luck